# Creating a simple interface like settings (ios)

Tags: ios, interface, uistoryboard, uiswitch, uitableview

I'm trying to create the same interface as in the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqRtR.png
This is my first application I've got running uiswitch, navigation bar and default background settings. How to create a cell with the text on the left and combine it with uiswitch? I use a storyboard.

Comment: you might read first the apple documentation for [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  as well as for the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No-no-no. SO ain't code factory. Gotta make some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by H2CO3 is totally right.

Well, I still find something for you, hope that's helpful.

Check the [link1](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) and [link2](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMStaticContentTableViewController)